# iTunes fails to subsribe to a podcast

Tags: itunes

I am using iTunes 10.2 on Windows 7 32bit
I am trying to subscribe to a video podcast (Tekzilla) and I am getting an error message.

[image]

I've been trying to do that for a couple of days and I'm getting the same error message so I guess the problem is on my side, somehow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. removing all the iTunes rules from the Windows Firewall and adding a single rule that allows all traffic for the iTunes executable solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try subscribing directly to the feed.

Under the "advanced" menu, select "subscribe to podcast…". Then, enter one of the feeds [found on Tekzilla's website](http://revision3.com/tekzilla/subscribe).

Comment: works. but I still wonder why I get this annoying error...